# Fetch from REST API not working in Azure VM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, azure, hosting

I have created a small webapp with React, NodeJS and MySQL. I did install Apache, Node and MySQL in Azure virtual machine and my React front-end (production build) works just fine, but I cannot fetch data from NodeJS REST API (server.js), I'm getting connection refused error in browser, even thought this works fine in my local VM. Here is my `App.js`

```
import './App.css';
import MenuItems from './components/Navbar/MenuItems';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import {AddItemToCart, DeleteItemFromCart, Counter} from './cart.js';
import Header from './header';
import Footer from './footer.js';

function App() {
  let store = createStore(Counter);
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState()
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])
  const [isLoaded, setStateToLoaded] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="content">
      
        <h1>My webapp</h1>
      <Header></Header>
      <div className='navbar'>
        {MenuItems.MenuItems.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index} onClick={() => setSelectedItem(item.title)}
          style={{cursor: "pointer"}}>{item.title}</li>
        ))}
        {selectedItem && (
          <h1>{selectedItem}</h1>
        )}
        {(selectedItem == 'Products') &&
          <div><GetProductsHtml/></div>
        }
        </div>

      
        <Footer></Footer>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  );
  
  async function initProducts() {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/listProducts`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
          setProducts(response.result);
          console.log(response.result);
          setStateToLoaded(true);
  }
      )
    }
    }

function GetProductsHtml() {
    initProducts()
    const AddItem = (id) => {
      console.log(id)
      store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()))
      store.dispatch(AddItemToCart(id))
    }
    return products.map(products =>
      <div key={products.ProductID}>
        <h2>{products.ProductName}</h2>
        <h2>{products.ProductDescription}</h2>
        <h2>{products.ProductQuantity} units available</h2>
        
        <button onClick={AddItem(products.ProductID)}>Add to cart</button>
        <button onClick=/*{AddItem(products.ProductID)}*/"">Show cart</button>
        </div>
    );
}

}

export default App;
```

Here is my `server.js`:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
const http = require('http');
var connected = false;
const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 5000;

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Node server is listening for requests...", host, port)
 })

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  user: "user1",
  password: "my_password",
  database: "mywebappdatabase"
});
app.use(cors({origin: '*'}));
app.get('/listProducts', function (req, res) {
    if (connected == false) {
      con.connect()
      connected = true;
    }
        //if (err) throw err;
        con.query("SELECT * FROM Products", function (err, result, fields) {
          //if (err) throw err;
          console.log(result);
          res.send({ result })
        });
      
 })
```

The problem is probably related to IP addresses I'm using. 127.0.0.1 should work since the MySQL server is hosted inside Azure VM, but I'm not sure. Here is the error message I get to Chrome console:
[image]

This works well on my local PC, but not in Azure VM. Could I have some advise on the problem? Thanks in advance.

Edit: My `/var/www/html` directory:
[image]

Comment: Any advise guys?

Answer (score 0):

Pls check that have you enabled port 5000 in the network security group of your VM network interface? You can check it here, click `add inbound port rule` to add a new one:

[image]

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: I had that port opened, do you know is VM restart required after updating port rules?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer, no, it's not required. How's going now?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer, Based on your error exception, seems your app is accessing host : http://127.0.0.1:5000/, you should change it as your VM public IP address. like : http://<your vm public IP>:5000/

Comment: I entered my VM public IP address to browser URL bar like 75.112.234.84:5000/listProducts but it didn't return JSON from database like it does in my local setup. It might be easier to use Azure App Service instead of VM for hosting a web app.